# PHP modulus operator for doubles

Tags: php, double, modulo

I read [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php#Hcom42066) that:

> Modulus with non integer numbers will give unpredictable results.

However, I tried [to play a bit with it](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/qcb-ymi), and it seems to give pretty predictable results:

```
function mod($a, $b) {
    echo "$a % $b = " . ($a % $b) . '<br>';
}
mod(10.3, 4);
mod(10.3, 2);
mod(-5.1, 3);

// OUTPUT:
//   10.3 % 4 = 2
//   10.3 % 2 = 0
//   -5.1 % 3 = -2
```

In other words, the `double` seems to be converted to `integer` first.

Is there any definition of how `%` works when the first operand is `double`?

Comment: Perhaps it should read "may give unexpected results".

Comment: Could you please provide an example of such unexpected result?

Answer (score 5):

use:

```
fmod(10.3, 4)
```

I too had to do the same thing but I noticed doubles are converted to int and using fmod returns a double.

If this helps

From http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php

`The result of the modulus operator % has the same sign as the dividend — that is, the result of $a % $b will have the same sign as $a.`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Note that I'm not interested in the `double` remainder (i.e. what `fmod` returns), but rather in understanding of how `%` works when the first operand is `double`.

Comment: @MishaMoroshko I edited my answer if it helps on what you were looking for.

Comment: Thanks for trying, but unfortunately your answer doesn't really address the question.